# How to check whether Java stream is ordered?

Tags: java, java-stream

Is it possible to check if a Java `Stream` is ordered or not?

By unordered `Stream` I mean, for instance a stream on which `unordered()` was called.

Comment: any such check will consume the Stream. is that acceptable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to check if a stream is unordered you need to get characteristics of stream's spliterator and test is 3th bit is set to one.

You can use this code snippet as an example:

```
    Stream<Integer> sorted = Stream.of(1, 2, 3).sorted();
    System.out.println((sorted.spliterator().hasCharacteristics(Spliterator.SORTED));

    sorted = Stream.of(1, 2, 3).sorted().unordered();
    System.out.println((sorted.spliterator().hasCharacteristics(Spliterator.SORTED));

    Stream<Integer> unordered = Stream.of(1, 2, 3).unordered();
    System.out.println((unordered.spliterator().hasCharacteristics(Spliterator.SORTED));

    unordered = Stream.of(1, 2, 3);
    System.out.println((unordered.spliterator().hasCharacteristics(Spliterator.SORTED));
```

For more details you can check [Spliterator documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html).

**UPDATE:**
But invocation of `spliterator()` is a terminal operation on the stream, what means that no more operations can be performed on it. In spite of that the elements will nor be consumed, what makes it possible to create new stream with the same characteristics in way:

```
    Spliterator<Integer> spliterator = unordered.spliterator();
    System.out.println(spliterator.hasCharacteristics(Spliterator.SORTED));
    Stream<Integer> newStream = StreamSupport.stream(spliterator, unordered.isParallel())
                                             .onClose(unordered::close); // in case if you have some close handlers on initial stream
```

Thanks @Holger for pointing the last moment.

Comment: You can simply call `.hasCharacteristics(Spliterator.ORDERED)` on the spliterator. But keep in mind that calling `spliterator()` on a `Stream` consumes the stream.

Comment: @Holger, thanks, I've missed that `spliterator()` is a terminal operation. But it actually doesn't consume the stream.

Comment: It does consume the stream. I suppose, what you mean is, it doesn’t consume the elements.